# if statement is not executing correctly

Tags: c++, class, if-statement, instance

When i make the initial input age = 10, then the if-else statement should print out first "You are young" and then after age is incremented by 3, it should print out "You are teenager".However, it prints out "You are old" executing the wrong if-else statement.There would be a problem with my `amIOld()` function.The ranges or conditions are (age>=13 and age<18) (age<13) and (age>=18) for the statements remaining the same.

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

class Person{
    public:
        int age;
        Person(int initialAge);
        void amIOld();
        void yearPasses();

        private :

    };

    Person::Person(int initialAge){

        age=initialAge;

            if(age<0){
              cout << " Age is not valid, setting age to 0." << endl;
              age=0;
            }
    }

    void Person::amIOld(){         //Check if-else statements of this function// 

        if(age>=13 && age<18){

            cout << "You are teenager." << endl;
        }
                                  
      else{
          if (age<13){

           cout << "You are a young." << endl;
          }
    
        if(age>=18){ 
            cout << "You are old." << endl;
        }
      }
      
    }
    

    void Person::yearPasses(){
        
           age = age+3;                
    }

int main(){
    int t;
    int age;
    cin >> t;
    for(int i=0; i < t; i++) {
        cin >> age;
        Person p(age);
        p.amIOld();
        for(int j=0; j < 3; j++) {
            p.yearPasses(); 
        }
        p.amIOld();
      
        cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are calling yearPasses 3 times in the for loop and yearPasses adds 3 to age, so you are adding 9 to age

Comment: You do `p.yearPasses();` in a loop 3 times, this changes age from `10` to `19` and `19` is already `old` for you (yikes).

Comment: ya guys enough of sarcasm and jokes the main() function is not editable

Comment: so i have to do age=age+1 ???

Comment: There was no sarcasm in my comment (except for that yikes at the end). `yearPasses()` adds `3` to `age`. I don't know what the code is supposed to do, but that looks suspicious at least.

Comment: ya that age=age+1 worked thanks instead of using age=age+3

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that `if ... else if...` ladder can be made much simpler if it starts at one end rather than in the middle. So: `if (age < 13) ... else if (age < 18) ... else ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The j loop runs three times.  Each time through, it calls p.yearPasses(), which adds 3 to age.  So the end age is 10 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 19, which is "old" according to p.amIOld().